# Attaching files to comments?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, comments, attachment

Are there any guides/gems available that allow you to attach files to a comment.

I have already setup comments just need some way to add attachments to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip
>
> http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads